# need help regarding blank javascript pages

Tags: firefox

I’m using Ubuntu Firefox on Linux. I play a web game and I use about 100 tabs to play it. When I go through the tabs with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> it will open a window  with JavaScript in the address bar and the page will be blank. My question is how can I stop it from popping up?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: sorry it says i need 10 reputation to post an image.

Comment: i just made the image my profile pic

Comment: Does the same thing happen, if you disable all Firefox add-ons and plug-ins (except those, that you may need for the game, e. g. Flash Player)?

Comment: yes it still does. thanks for helping with the image.

Comment: Does the same thing happen in other browsers, e. g. Chrome/Chromium, Epiphany, Konqueror, or Opera?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue has nothing to do with the browser let alone Ubuntu. Even though some element may *look* like links, it is possible that it points to a bogus "URL". These elements can have a so-called *event handler* registered to them which can trigger on certain events, like clicking. Depending on the web application, it can then simply change the page URL or dispatch an AJAX request.

Example HTML code with an inline Javascript event handler:

```
<a href="javascript:" onclick="alert('You have clicked me!');">some link</a>
```

Unless you write Javascript code yourself, you will not be able to trigger these actions by just clicking on it.